# Does Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter (USB-C to HDMI) support Windows/Ubuntu (on MacBook Pro 15" 2017)?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, hdmi, video-adapter

I have **no problem** using this adapter [Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter (USB-C to HDMI)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=63f6a39e19c7c4143b12b7973240117d79e0557ed961ba85f22ed0938852fe9c8d45e65aa4e4ebb5ca38eb49c95ae4b68b697cde8b584391fb83afa8e4d29a194bf9a4959ee399e989af8289a1dac4dc76dbf6bb1265bd960bb950129d445456) on **macOS Big Sur** with MacBook Pro 15" 2017 (Radeon Pro 555 2 GB), connecting to 4k@60Hz external display.

But when booting to **windows 10** (bootcamp) it behaves strangely.
When connecting display for the **first time, it works OK**. But resolution is not display's native or refresh rate is low (not what display supports).

**When I try to change it**, display goes into infinite restart loop (not MacBook, but display itself), it looks like display being disconnected and connected again over and over. It shows black screen, but Windows desktop scaling changes, MacBook screen blinks endlessly once per 5-7 seconds. If I disconnect HDMI cable, blinking stops and I can use computer.

My first clue was Apple adapter not supporting any OS except macOS (I want to use Windows and Ubuntu Linux), but I didn't find any information on this, so I ask here.

Did anyone try using USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter with Windows or Ubuntu?
Does it work with Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: So is Windows loading a different driver?

Comment: @SolarMike not sure I understand question. Different from macOS? Should be so, it is another OS, so another driver. Windows drivers: graphics is AMD (some AMD control panel installed), Monitor in Device Manager is "Generic PnP Display", in desktop resolution settings - Phillips 276E... (proper display name)